# Entity Framework: Not able to use migration command when entityFramework dll is referenced manually (Not installed from Nuget package)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am aware that 'Enable-Migrations' and 'Add Migrations' commands are used for migrations on package manager console. But in my project, we have not installed EF from nuget. We are explicitely (manaully) referencing EF's dll in bin folder.

Now, I am not able to run migration command. Could anybody help in this context.

Please note that we are using Code-First approach.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands are part of the NuGet package and are added when installing the package. In your current project you can remove the reference to EntityFramework.dll and install the package. Another alternative would be to use [migrate.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ618307.aspx) but the experience is far more inferior than running commands from the Package Manager Console.